# How to get TFS build on a dedicated server

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build

I have my desktop with VS 2010 professional installed, a virtual machine with TFS 2010 installed and a second virtual machine on which I want the builds to work onto.[image]

Thats what I'm trying to say.

The two virtual machines are on the same domain, the VS 2010 is on a different domain.

Is it just configuring the build agent?

Hope this makes sence.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your Visual Studio project build on a dedicated server you have to setup a Team Build definition, see [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181716.aspx) on the MSDN for more information.

Comment: But how do you make the connection between the TFS machine and the machine to act on?

Comment: I don't understand "act on"... Maybe this is a Virtual Machine related issue? You have to create a virtual network between the VM and your host computer if you want to enable network exchange between both. Is this what you want to know?

Comment: Ok act on probably wasn't the best way to phase it. I write code on my desktop (VS 2010 machine) and use the TFS Server to build it. The project is a copier, where it copies from an external server to my VS machine, but I want when it builds to do it on the 3rd machine instead of the VS machine. Hope that explains it better

Comment: Sorry, disread my last comment, looked at the wrong link. So What this means is just to change the drop folder?

Comment: You're trying to automatically deploy your built projects to that third machine?  Like deploying a web site, for example?